# How to add posts using own plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api

Creating a wordpress plugin and need this plugin to automatically add posts to wordpress when it installs. What is the better solution to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `register_activation_hook` to carry out any custom functions (like adding posts) after the plugin is initialised.

```
 function myplugin_activate() {

     // Add your posts here...
 }
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
```

That way, once the plugin is installed, and activated, `myplugin_activate()` will fire, and carry out any logic you put there.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I've been looking for. And is this [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/imelgrat/bbc26d3d0724d29a8e0f7da5832e7767/raw/416c7dec3d41a846d64739e98f270ce40cf26d4e/bulk-post-create.php) a suitable way for adding posts?

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine for pulling data from another source and inserting them as posts in Wordpress.